# Joomla! create new user

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm trying to make creating a new user easier.

Users >> User Manager >> Add New User

I have a additional component tab that wants a first name and last name that we populate first. However, what I'd really like to happen is concatenate those two fields and put it into the Login Name field on the Account Details Tab.

The code looks pretty similar to whats already there for all the other tabs. New `startTabSet` with a loop for field labels and field inputs.

Is this possible and how so?

This is the Addition Detail Tab with the first and last name fields
[image]

I want those values that the user enters above to show up below. In place of the randomly generated user name and password.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty vague question

Comment: How so? Explain what you would want expanded on.

Comment: I added a little more that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple, I created an `onchange` javascript event on the name fields and had it get the value of name and place that value in  the login name field.